# Does MPI_Reduce need an existing pointer for the receive buffer?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, mpi

The [MPI documentation](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2.x/www3/MPI_Reduce.html) asserts that the adress of address of the receive buffer (`recvbuf`) is significant only at root. Meaning that the memory may not be allocated in the other processes. This is confirmed by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796403/about-mpi-reduce).

```
int MPI_Reduce(const void *sendbuf, void *recvbuf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype,
               MPI_Op op, int root, MPI_Comm comm)
```

At first I thought that `recvbuf` did not even have to exist: that the memory for `recvbuf` itself did not have to be allocated (eg by dynamical allocation). Unfortunately (it took me a lot of time to understand my mistake!), it seems that even if the memory that it points to is not valid, the pointer itself has to exist.

See below for the code I have in mind, with a version that gives a segfault, and one that does not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   // MPI initialization
    int world_rank, world_size;
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    int n1 = 3, n2 = 10; // Sizes of the 2d arrays

    long **observables = (long **) malloc(n1 * sizeof(long *));
    for (int k = 0 ; k < n1 ; ++k) {
        observables[k] = (long *) calloc(n2, sizeof(long));
        for (long i = 0 ; i < n2 ; ++i) {
            observables[k][i] = k * i * world_rank; // Whatever
        }
    }

    long **obs_sum; // This will hold the sum on process 0
#ifdef OLD  // Version that gives a segfault
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        obs_sum = (long **) malloc(n2 * sizeof(long *));
        for (int k = 0 ; k < n2 ; ++k) {
            obs_sum[k] = (long *) calloc(n2, sizeof(long));
        }
    }
#else // Correct version
   // We define all the pointers in all the processes.
    obs_sum = (long **) malloc(n2 * sizeof(long *));
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        for (int k = 0 ; k < n2 ; ++k) {
            obs_sum[k] = (long *) calloc(n2, sizeof(long));
        }
    }
#endif

    for (int k = 0 ; k < n1 ; ++k) {
        // This is the line that results in a segfault if OLD is defined
        MPI_Reduce(observables[k], obs_sum[k], n2, MPI_LONG, MPI_SUM, 0,
                   MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    // You may free memory here

    return 0;
}
```

Am I interpreting this correctly? What is the rationale behind this behavior?

Comment: `world_rank == 0` is true or false? What do you think happens on `long **obs_sum;` and then you do `obs_sum[k]` without initializing `obs_sum` ?

Comment: Do you know about MPI? The program is to be sent in multiple copies (processes) with world_rank = 0, 1, 2, ... `obs_sum` will be used *only* on process 0 (that's why `obs_sum[k]` does not need to be allocated). My question is: if `obs_sum` is completely useless on processes 1, 2, ... why does it have to exist at all?

Comment: That said, you should be right, writing `obs_sum[k]` may imply that it is allocated even if completely useless.

Comment: The `obs_sum[k]`  is equal to `*(obs_sum + k)` and only _writing_ it is enough for the * operator to execute on an invalid pointer value (as `obs_sum` is not initialized), which is enough for undefined behavior and seg fault. So `world_rank` is `!= 0`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not MPI, but the fact that you are passing `obs_sum[k]`, but you haven't defined/allocated it at all.

```
for (int k = 0 ; k < n1 ; ++k) {
    // This is the line that results in a segfault if OLD is defined
    MPI_Reduce(observables[k], obs_sum[k], n2, MPI_LONG, MPI_SUM, 0,
               MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

Even if `MPI_Reduce()` is not getting its value, the generated code will get `obs_sum` (undefined and not allocated), add `k` to it and try to read this pointer (segfault) to be passed to `MPI_Reduce()`.

For example the allocation of the rows should be sufficient for it to work:

```
#else // Correct version
      // We define all the pointers in all the processes.
      obs_sum = (long **) malloc(n2 * sizeof(long *));
      // try commenting out the following lines
      // if (world_rank == 0) {
      //   for (int k = 0 ; k < n2 ; ++k) {
      //     obs_sum[k] = (long *) calloc(n2, sizeof(long));
      //   }
      // }
#endif
```

I would allocate a 2D array as a flat array - I really *hate* this array-of-arrays representation. Wouldn't this be better?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   // MPI initialization
    int world_rank, world_size;
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    int n1 = 3, n2 = 10; // Sizes of the 2d arrays

    long *observables = (long *) malloc(n1*n2*sizeof(long));
    for (int k = 0 ; k < n1 ; ++k) {
        for (long i = 0 ; i < n2 ; ++i) {
            observables[k*n2+i] = k * i * world_rank; // Whatever
        }
    }

    long *obs_sum = nullptr; // This will hold the sum on process 0
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        obs_sum = (long *) malloc(n1*n2*sizeof(long));
    }

    MPI_Reduce(observables, obs_sum, n1*n2, MPI_LONG, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    // You may free memory here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. And thanks for the suggestion, although it may require a significant to my whole code.

Comment: I see. To make the long story short, the horrific array-of-arrays style was adopted in "Numerical Recipes in C", and A LOT of scientific computing in C got it. Unfortunately it leads to a lot of troubles in handling the non-flat memory, as you have seen with this example, possible performance penalties for a minimal syntactical sugar to let C be similar to Fortran. And guess what, Fortran memory layout for 2D arrays is flat.